# jQuery Pagination from Given Records ID

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have found many pagination coding for jQuery plugin. Everything is working fine. But my need is, 
i have 20 records in table.I want to display only one records at a time with **First - Previous - Next - Last** .     when i enter particular Records Id like '15', It should show that details of 15 , and if i click next it show next Records Id..etc.

For eg.,

Rec Id :      15

First Name :  Gnaniyar

Last Name  : Zubair

> First    Previous  Next  Last

If i give record Id 10, it should show details of 10 th Record id ...and so on..

How to do in jQuery?

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Comment: It's hard to answer that question without seeing how you have tried to do it. As you say there are many pagination techniques, could you post a bit of you code to give us an idea of how to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [traversing functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) to access the current selection's neighbours and search the elements that you are using to display your records. You can use the [effects functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) to animate the elements in and out. You should bind events to the links (back, forward etc.)